# need of sed or awk script that decodes some hex strings

Tags: string, awk, sed, hex, lex

Some obfuscated JQuery code (or for other programming reasons intentionally coded into hex) contains a bunch of arbitrary strings that look like

```
"\x2e\x68\x65\x2d\x76\x69\x65\x77"
```

This decodes **e.g.** to the string ".he-view".

I would like to pass this code through a script that converts all the "\xhh" characters into readable ASCII characters.

While I'm waiting for answers I'll set out to write a lex filter.

Just to be more precise: the code contains the above hex coded strings among JS code. The filter should echo the surrounding code and just convert the hex strings in place so that the result stays readable and syntactically correct.

Here again the task:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC "\x2e\x68\x65\x2d\x76\x69\x65\x77" DDD EEE
```

should yield

```
AAA,BBB,CCC ".he-view" DDD EEE
```

Practically, it doesn't play any role, whether the surrounding code is JS, JQuery or something else. The question was looking for a filter that converts all these hex strings in "" into readable ASCII. That the rest of the code should pass through is herewith expressively stated again.

In addition, I found that hex strings occur also quoted in pairs of single quotes (\').

And of course, the tool/script should be used as a filter, that is, give it the input file and it spits out the converted file such that all, call it, "hex-strings" are converted to readable ASCII.

FWIW, here is an excerpt of the document that has to be converted:

> ```
>    switchImg: function (b, c) {
>         var d = b.data("\x61\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x65");
>         d = d ? animation : "\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d";
>         if (d == "\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d") {
>             var f = ["\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6e", "\x66\x6c\x69\x70\x49\x6e\x48"];
>             d = f[Math.floor(Math.random() * f.length)]
>         };
>         var e = b.find("\x69\x6d\x67");
> ```

Comment: Can you give a simple complete document you want to translate? I can refine my answer if it should not work with that. But it should.

Comment: I don't see to have not given enough information in my original post and why I got a -1 for this.

Comment: Use `echo -e AAA,BBB,CCC "\x2e\x68\x65\x2d\x76\x69\x65\x77" DDD EEE` - as I said

Comment: echo is not the solution. How would you be able to fulfill the postulation that you can pass the input file to "echo" and achieve the desired result?

Comment: `while read line ; do echo -e "$line" ; done < input.file`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it garbles the input file and leaves strings like
"x7ax6fx6fx6dx73x74x65x70" in the output. It eats up all backslashes though.

Comment: Yes, that might be a problem depending on the input. Why don't you give a near-real-world example? You have been asked for that multiple times since yesterday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112892/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-krischu).

Answer (score 1):

At least in bash, you can simply use the `echo` builtin command:

```
echo -e "\x2e\x68\x65\x2d\x76\x69\x65\x77"
```

Output:

```
.he-view
```

Check `help echo` for it's manual.

Comment: For the string alone his may work, but I just want to filter out the "\x..." strings and discard the rest.

Comment: You wrote: `I would like to pass this code through a script that converts all the "\xhh" characters into readable ASCII characters.`.

Comment: Of course `echo -e "foo \x2e\x68\x65\x2d\x76\x69\x65\x77 bar"` would work as well.

Comment: Excuses, if I wasn't precise enough. The code contains these strings among other stuff. The filter should just filter out the hex code enclosed in "".

Comment: @Krischu don't just apologize in a comment, edit your question to be more precise and include concise, testable and truly representative sample input and expected output. And do it quick before your question gets downvoted and closed for being unclear. See [ask] if you're not sure what's required to ask a question on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem now is a lex (flex) script that I compile into a filter:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A yytext[i]
#define B yytext[i+1]
#define F yytext[0]
#define L yytext[strlen(yytext)-1]
main()
{
   while (yylex());
}

%}

%%

\"([\\]x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])*\"|\'([\\]x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])*\' { int i=1; 
      printf("%c",F);
      while(yytext[i]!=F) {
          i++;i++;/* skip 2, backslash and  x*/
          printf("%c",16*(A <'a'? (A-'0'): (A-'a'+10))|\
                         (B <'a'? (B-'0'): (B-'a'+10)));
          i++;i++; /* skip the two hex digits */
      }
      printf("%c",L); /* append \" or \' */
}

. { ECHO ; }
%%
```